# Windows permissions: How to let PHP (on SERVERA) write to serverB

Tags: php, windows, permissions

I'am trying to copy a file from a windows serverA (server 2012 R2 Standard) to a windows serverB (server 2012 Standard).
ServerA runs IIS 8 (don't know if thats important or not)

I'am using this PHP script (hlutest.php) executed from a client computer invocation: serverA\hlutest:

```
<?php echo `whoami`; 
$file = 'somefile.ini';
//$newfile = "\\\\serverB\\SYS\\Quality\\Documents\\somefile.ini";  // This does not work
$newfile = "C:\\weg\\somefile.ini";                                     // This works, copy to local server

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "<br>failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

Whoami returns: nt authority\iusr
So the user is iusr

When copying to local serverA the script is succesfull.
However copying to remote serverB causes permission error.
PHP Warning:  copy(\serverB\SYS\quality\Documents\somefile.ini): failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\vak\hlutest.php on line 7

Already tried to set permissions for user "IUSR" on serverB. No succes.

Can anyone point out what steps (step by step) I should take to get copy from serverA to serverB working?
Or point me to a thorough tutorial on how to solve this?

Comment: Post it with curl from server A to B and save it on B?